# asp.net inserts multiple rows

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

So I have this webpage in asp.net.
I'm working with BO and DAL-classes. This is the insert I use:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Insert a record.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>1 on success, 0 on error</returns>
    [DataObjectMethodAttribute(DataObjectMethodType.Insert, true)]
    public static int InsertOrder(Order order)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

        string sql =
          "INSERT INTO tblOrders (NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, PC, DATE, BOOK_ID, COUNT, AMOUNT, DELIVERED, DDATE, PAID, PDATE) " +
          "SELECT @orderNAME, @orderADDRESS, @orderCITY, @orderPC, @orderDATE, @orderBOOK_ID, @orderCOUNT, @orderAMOUNT, @orderDELIVERED, @orderDDATE, @orderPAID, @orderPDATE " +
          "FROM tblOrders";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderNAME", order.OrderNAME);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderADDRESS", order.OrderADDRESS);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderCITY", order.OrderCITY);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderPC", order.OrderPC);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderDATE", order.OrderDATE);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderBOOK_ID", order.OrderBOOK_ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderCOUNT", order.OrderCOUNT);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderAMOUNT", order.OrderAMOUNT);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderDELIVERED", order.OrderDELIVERED);
        if (order.OrderDELIVERED == true)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderDDATE", order.OrderDDATE);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderDDATE", order.OrderDDATE).Value = System.DBNull.Value;
        }
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderPAID", order.OrderPAID);
        if (order.OrderPAID == true)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderPDATE", order.OrderPDATE);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderPDATE", order.OrderPDATE).Value = System.DBNull.Value;
        }

        conn.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        return i;
    }
```

Everything works, except, every time I exectue this code, it doubles the rows it inserts. So the first time I insert something, it inserts the same row 2 times (with different ID's, but except for that, all the other data is the same), the next time, it does this 4 times, the time after that it does that 8 times, ...

I don't know what's causing this problem.

Comment: @RahulSingh, No, it's not weird and perfectly alright to do. Mainly done for testing purpose though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's because of your `INSERT` statement. It rather has to be a simple `INSERT` query rather than `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM`. It doubles up because it inserts those many number of rows, as many present in the table at the time of inserts.

```
INSERT INTO tblOrders (NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, PC, DATE, BOOK_ID, 
COUNT, AMOUNT, DELIVERED, DDATE, PAID, PDATE) 
VALUES (@orderNAME, @orderADDRESS, @orderCITY, @orderPC, @orderDATE, 
       @orderBOOK_ID, @orderCOUNT, @orderAMOUNT, 
       @orderDELIVERED, @orderDDATE, @orderPAID, @orderPDATE);
```

Again, you are using reserve words as column name like `NAME, DATE, COUNT` etc. Try escaping them using backtiques.

Comment: This worked! I altered the code from a not-auto incrementing ID, so I guess that's where I went wrong. Thank you very much!